# Kendo UI Asp.Net MVC ComboBox filter not updating from server

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox, kendo-ui, telerik

I am using u ComboBox component from Telerik (Kendo UI).
I followed all the steps mentioned on the Telerik site but somehow I am not able to filter correctly via the server. The filter works fine, everything gets passed except one issue. The filter only applys if I am clicking somewhere else so that the list hides from the combobox and if I re-click it then, the filter applys. So I have to toggle the list from the combobox and then I have to open the list again. This is very strange due I followed all the steps from Telerik.
I am filtering with my server which works correctly.

**Code for my ComboBox:**

```
        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
      .Name("ModellDrop")
      .Placeholder("Modell...")
      .DataTextField("ModellKurz")
      .DataValueField("ModellKurz")
      .HtmlAttributes(new { ng_model = "Modell.ModellKurz" })
      .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
      .AutoBind(false)
      .DataSource(source =>
      {
          source.Read(read =>
          {
              read.Action("GetModell", "UserApi")
                .Data("filterModell");
          })
          .ServerFiltering(true);
      })
      .CascadeFrom("HerstellerDrop")
    )
```

**Code from my ServerSide:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetModell(string Hersteller, string ModellFilter)
    {
        var List = _context.tbl_Hersteller_Modell.AsQueryable();

        if(Hersteller != null)
        {
            List = List.Where(x => x.HerstKurz == Hersteller);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ModellFilter))
        {
            List = List.Where(p => p.ModellKurz.Contains(ModellFilter));
        }

        return Json(List, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**Code from my Client Side:**

```
function filterModell() {
    var Value = jQuery("#HerstellerDrop").data("kendoComboBox").value();
    var FilterModell = jQuery("#ModellDrop").data("kendoComboBox").value();
    return {
        Hersteller: Value,
        ModellFilter: FilterModell
    };
}
```

Is something missing there or why is the list not automaticaly refreshing??

Comment: May I look at the filterModell function?

Comment: I edited my Question @Clarice